# Which equality/comparison operators are synthesized for heterogeneous spaceship operator definitions?

Tags: c++, c++20, spaceship-operator

C++20 introduced the new spaceship operator `<=>` which allows for synthesizing equality and comparison operators based on the strength of the ordering of the three-way comparison.

However, it appears that when working with following simple toy example performing a heterogeneous comparison, it is unable to synthesize equality operators -- but is still succeeds to synthesize ordering operators -- despite having `std::strong_ordering`:

```cpp
#include <compare>
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
struct Wrapper {
    int value;

    auto operator<=>(const Wrapper&) const = default;

    template <typename U>
    auto operator<=>(const Wrapper<U>& other) const {
        return value <=> other.value;
    }
};

void test() {
    // Same type equality -- works
    assert(Wrapper<Foo>{42} == Wrapper<Foo>{42});

    // Heterogeneous comparison -- works
    assert(Wrapper<Foo>{42} < Wrapper<Bar>{45});

    // Heterogeneous equality -- doesn't work?
    assert(Wrapper<Foo>{42} == Wrapper<Bar>{42});
}
```

On GCC, this gives the following error:

```
<source>: In function 'void test()':
<source>:26:29: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Wrapper<Foo>' and 'Wrapper<Bar>')
   26 |     assert(Wrapper<Foo>{42} == Wrapper<Bar>{42});
      |            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |            |                   |
      |            Wrapper<Foo>        Wrapper<Bar>
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sr46rznKe)</kbd>

From what I can tell from [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons#Strong_ordering), the automatic synthesized operators for a strongly-ordered `<=>` should include equality -- but yet this doesn't seem to be the case with heterogeneous comparisons, but it is for homogeneous comparisons.

This fails on `gcc`, `clang`, and even MSVC -- so I am pretty sure this is the correct behavior, albeit unexpected. I know this can be fixed by defining a custom `operator==` *as well*, but my question is mostly *why this happens in the first place*, and what can I *expect* to be generated from a heterogeneous `operator<=>` definition?

Comment: `<=>` will generate `<` `<=` `>` `>=` operators.  And `==` will generate `!=` operator.  (Keep in mind that `==` may be implicitly defaulted.)

Comment: @Eljay Oh. Then it appears I completely misunderstood the way that `<=>` worked then. I was under the (mistaken) impression that `<=>` generated all 6 and not only those 4 -- at least when using `strong_ordering`. Playing around with the godbolt link I realize that `<=>` isn't needed for the default (homogeneous) equality operator, so it appears I was off-base with my understanding. Please feel free to turn this comment into an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: All good.  At one time, the `<=>` proposal was to generate all 6, as you had thought/remembered.  But it got revised to just the 4 because the general case for equality was suboptimal.

Comment: @Eljay Ahh, thank you for that -- that would definitely explain my misunderstanding then! From what I recall back during standardization, `operator<=>` generated all 6 -- but explicitly allowed the case of `operator==` to override equality for cases like `std::string` to prevent sub-optimal generation. I guess in the end they just dropped it to generate the 4.

Comment: @Human-Compiler: Well, it still does all 6 if a suitable `operator<=>` is *defaulted* (inside the class), since it generates `operator==(…)=default` then for convenience.